# How can I get more accurate search results from an AutoSuggestBox?

Tags: c#, windows, sorting, autosuggest, win-universal-app

I'm using an AutoSuggestBox in a Windows Universal app on Win10. I can filter the suggestions just fine, but the order is messed up. For instance, in my case, the suggestions are city names. When I type 't' in the box, I expect to see 'Tehran' first, not 'Athens' because it is at the top of the List that contains all the cities with a 't'.

I realize I need a list sorted by

```
City.Name.IndexOf(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

but what is the simplest and most efficient way to achieve this? My code follows:

```
    private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Only get results when it was a user typing
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            foreach (City myCity in Cities)
            {
                if (myCity.Name.IndexOf(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    myList.Add(myCity.Name);
                }
            }

            sender.ItemsSource = myList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty this

```
if (myCity.Name.StartsWith("t"))
    myList.Add(myCity.Name);
```

Comment: The issue with this is it doesn't include all the other cities that have 't' in them, right below the cities that start with 't'

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed the condition to

```
if (myCity.Name.IndexOf(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the StartsWith & Contains functions.

```
if (myCity.Name.StartsWith("t"))
myList.Add(myCity.Name);
if (myCity.Name.Contains("t"))
myList.Add(myCity.Name);
```

But they would have to be used in separate foreach loops. The first one filters out all cities starting with T & next one filters all cities containing T.

If you want to use it one foreach loop you could do this:

```
if (myCity.Name.StartsWith("t"))
myList1.Add(myCity.Name);
if (myCity.Name.Contains("t") && myCity.Name.IndexOf(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
myList2.Add(myCity.Name);
```

You could then merge both the lists & make it as the itesmSource.